# Give Equal Margin to text from both sides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When i write some content in div , It shows like[image]

But I want it to show with equal margin from right like[image]

I have tried margin,padding and every solution but nothing work.So How to achieve this to make webpages look good?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

`text-align: justify`

```
HTML:

<p class="info">
This is a long piece of text that doesn't make sense 
yet you are still reading it up to this point and even up 
to now and more.
</p>

CSS:

p.info { text-align: justify }
```